# Hibernate tools - POJO ordering

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, hibernate-tools

I'm using the latest version of Hibernate Tools from JBoss Studio / Eclipse to generate Java POJOs from my database schema.

When there is a get method that gets further objects I want to have these returned in a specific order. Obviously I can just edit the class file however these changes will then be lost if these files are re-generated if there are any further schema changes.

Research has showed it should be possible to add these options using hibernate reverse engineering XML config or possibly a hibernate hbm xml file.
I can't seem to get these to work and am hoping somebody could provide an example config that would work.

I have created a very simple DB to illustrate the problem.

SQL Schema:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `pupil`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pupil`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `pupil` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `school_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `forename` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `gender` enum('M','F') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `fk_pupils_schools_idx` (`school_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_pupils_schools` FOREIGN KEY (`school_id`) REFERENCES `school` (`ID`)     ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Table structure for table `school`
--

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `school`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `school` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

This results in two POJOs.

Pupil.java

```
package hibernateExample.db;  
// Generated 20-Sep-2014 15:34:31 by Hibernate Tools 4.0.0

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * Pupil generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "pupil", catalog = "test")
public class Pupil implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int id;
    private School school;
    private String forename;
    private String surname;
    private String gender;

    public Pupil() {
    }

    public Pupil(int id, School school, String forename, String surname,
            String gender) {
        this.id = id;
        this.school = school;
        this.forename = forename;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "school_id", nullable = false)
    public School getSchool() {
        return this.school;
    }

    public void setSchool(School school) {
        this.school = school;
    }

    @Column(name = "forename", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getForename() {
        return this.forename;
    }

    public void setForename(String forename) {
        this.forename = forename;
    }

    @Column(name = "surname", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getSurname() {
        return this.surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    @Column(name = "gender", nullable = false, length = 2)
    public String getGender() {
        return this.gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

}
```

School.java. The getPupils method needs to have an OrderBy annotation added on POJO creation. This probably needs to be a List rather than a Set too?

```
package hibernateExample.db;
// Generated 20-Sep-2014 15:34:31 by Hibernate Tools 4.0.0

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * School generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "school", catalog = "test")
public class School implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Set<Pupil> pupils = new HashSet<Pupil>(0);

    public School() {
    }

    public School(String name, Set<Pupil> pupils) {
        this.name = name;
        this.pupils = pupils;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", length = 200)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "school")
    public Set<Pupil> getPupils() {
        return this.pupils;
    }

    public void setPupils(Set<Pupil> pupils) {
        this.pupils = pupils;
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: @OrderBy annotation will be enough, even if it is a List or Set. What output did you get? http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/04/hibernate-tip-sort-and-order.html

Comment: @user23123412, how do I get this annotation added at the point of POJO generation?

A couple of examples I've found online don't seem to have any effect and there seems to be no output in eclipse to help debug where the problem might lie

Answer (score 0):

Example to add the an annotation via reverse engineering xml:
You can see how easy it is to tweak the scope class mete attibute in below example.

```
<table name="organization">
        <meta attribute="scope-class">@Proxy(lazy=false) public</meta>
        <meta attribute="extra-import">org.hibernate.annotations.Proxy</meta>
        ....rest of config.....
</table>
```

You could on a field level using scope-field attribute.
Full meta attributes at this [link](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/latest/en/hibernatetools/html/codegen.html#d0e6365)