# How to generate List instead of Set with Hibernate tools reverse engineering?

Tags: java, hibernate

I would like to know how I can get in POJOS generated by Hibernate tools when doing reverse engineering of a database the collections of relationships (OneToMany, ManyToMany) like List instead of Set.

Is there any way to specify in the file reveng.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Answer depends on engineering pipeline. I use *hibernate-tools* 4.3.5.Final and Ant task *hibernatetool* with notable configurations:

- `<hbm2hbmxml/>` for HBM files generation;
- `<hbm2java jdk5="true" ejb3="true"/>` to create Java classes from HBM. Solution is in HBM contents.

#### Is there any way to specify in the file reveng.xml?

**No.** *hbm2hbmxml* is configured by *reveng.xml*. [Péter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2232784) suggests to specify desired type in `<column/>`, but *OneToMany* has no column. Relationship may explicitly be defined as following

```xml
<table name="MY_TABLE">
    <foreign-key constraint-name="FK_TO_MY_TABLE_IN_OTHER_TABLE">
        <set property="otherTables"/>
    </foreign-key>
</table>
```

Notice `<set/>` element. There is no `<list/>` or other collection in *hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0* namespace. I have not found a way to change collection type in *reveng.xml* or via Ant task parameters, so every relationship in generated HBM is `<set>` element (in *hibernate-mapping-3.0* namespace).

#### Is there a way to change collection type?

**Yes.** HBM file must contain desired type element (`<list>`, `<bag>`, `<map>`, etc.) instead of `<set>`. By default Hibernate tools use templates in JAR folders *hbm* and *pojo*. Each of those may be overridden by files in subfolders of folder specified in *templatepath* attribute of *hibernatetool* Ant task. You need to provide custom FreeMaker templates in *hbm* folder with following modifications.

In the end of *persistentclass.hbm.ftl* replace

```
<#if c2h.getTag(property)!="version" && c2h.getTag(property)!="timestamp">
```

with (notice template name starts with *list*, desired collection type, and processed tag is *set*)

```
<#if c2h.getTag(property) == "set">
    <#include "list.hbm.ftl"/>
<#elseif c2h.getTag(property)!="version" && c2h.getTag(property)!="timestamp">
```

In *list.hbm.ftl* remove following line (because set has no index property)

```
<#assign indexValue = value.getIndex()>
```

and replace mandatory element

```
<list-index>
<#foreach column in indexValue.columnIterator>
    <#include "column.hbm.ftl">
</#foreach>
</list-index>
```

with (put whatever you like instead of `ID`, it is not present in generated Java code)

```xml
<list-index column="ID"/>
```

---

*List* implies order. I suggest to add `OrderBy` annotation with related entity ID field name. Add to *list.hbm.ftl* after `<#include "meta.hbm.ftl">`

```xml
<meta attribute="scope-get">@javax.persistence.OrderBy("id") public</meta>
```

[maggu suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25963364) to add *extra-import* meta attribute to have package name mentioned in class file only once, but in my experience it breaks build with undefined symbol.

Notice actual scope after annotation. There is no way to put it on separate line (whitespace gets trimmed).

Alternative to *scope hack* is adding specific annotation in *pojo* build stage (one with *hbm2java*) together with other annotations, e.g., add to *Ejb3PropertyGetAnnotation.ftl* within `<#elseif c2h.isCollection(property)>` block following line

```
<#if property.value.type.returnedClass.simpleName == "List">@javax.persistence.OrderBy("id")</#if>
```

---

`<list>` and `<bag>` lead to `new ArrayList<>(0)` as default field value, but *list* is exposed as useful *java.util.List*, while *bag* is only *java.util.Collection*. It should be possible to change this (also for *set*) via *collection-type* attribute, but it accepts only *org.hibernate.usertype.UserCollectionType* implementations, not JDK classes.

In my project I had to replace *Set* with *List* only for certain relationships, so my *list.hbm.ftl* contains `<#if property.name == "otherTables">`. You can adjust condition as needed.